# Consuming private API REST (Android + Symfony)

Tags: php, android, rest, symfony, authentication

I have a stateful php web application made in Symfony that uses cookies to keep alive the session of the logged user in the application(I have worked always like that, I'm really new in REST services).

I'm making a REST API using the business logic of this web application, so I can use it in different environments (Android at the moment).

In order to keep private the API, I follow the symfony cookbook(http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html), so the requests are served through a 'apikey' sent in header of every request.

At the moment, this 'apikey' is a dummy string hardcoded in my android code.

What I first thought to do with this 'apikey' is a login screen in Android that send to the API an user and password, those credential will be checked on the server side and if they are correct, send to the client a 'apikey'(based on those credentials) and then, somehow, store it in the client and then send it in header of every request of the API.

I'm misunderstanding something with this 'apikey' method? (probably yes, while I'm writting this it seems to me that this apikey is a more 'static' concept).
Isn't this idea a kind of 'stateful' that is against REST pattern? I mean, I keep stored something that is checked on every request.

What I want to achieve is to have a login in Android, check credentials in server side and then(if this check is ok) let the android app make calls to the API in a secure way...
How I should proceed then?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also learning such things with Android and Symfony. What i've come to understand is your API Key should be unique to every user, meaning that every user should have, as subscribed to your website, an API Key, which represents them. It will work like a unique login, except that using REST, you only need the API Key to be authentificated, instead of a login and a password. 
In this case, your API Key should be hard to find. I guess you should use the user's ID and login, since they have to be both unique identifier, and make something out of it, like encrypting.
If you've learn more since, it'd be a pleasure to hear from you experience.

Comment: I'm not very satisfied of what I have done so far, but I needed to move on... So, finally(as the API will be on a HTTPS server), in the symfony side I activated basic http authentication (`http_basic: ~` in security.yml) and then on the android side, I get the credentials from a login activity, I codify these credentials(in Base64) and then I send it to every request to the API(in header).

Comment: I've finally came up to some similar solution, i've been a special auth for the host api.mywebsite.com and then, could make a special provider using an API Key, under this host.
Finally, when the user will "log in", my server will send him the API Key, and it'll be stored in the database. I think it's a good solution, yet i'm not feeling comfortable with this kind of programming. 
Maybe could we have some skype conversation sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented the ApiKey "mode" in my Symfony web app.
From my perspective, after correct user connection (using login and password), you can generate a key resulting in the sha1 encryption of the concatation of any unique user info with the result of uniqid.